# Does multithreading make sense in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, multithreading

In winforms development you may create a `BackgroundWorker` to avoid locking the UI on a long running process.  In ASP.NET a POST/GET basically freezes until completion.  I don't see how adding a `Thread` would be of any benefit to this process.  Maybe if the `Thread` would speed completion (say on a multi-core server) it could help speed things up.

In the general sense I could use AJAX to make long calls without causing a "freeze" of the web page.  In this sense AJAX can be thought of as a substitute for threading.

Is that it?  Is threading pretty much useless on ASP.NET?

Comment: For reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163725.aspx (Asynchronous Pages in ASP.NET 2.0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multithreading can make requests faster if:

1. Each web request's work can be broken down into multiple tasks that can run in parallel
2. Each of those tasks is very CPU intensive ([CPU bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_bound)), or you have multiple I/O bound tasks on different I/O paths (see comments)
3. You can implement them using [fork/join parallelism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163340.aspx).

In that case, you can indeed use multithreading in ASP.NET.  A common mistake that people make is to spawn off threads and then not wait for them to complete- for instance "I am going to respond to the user while logging their purchase to the database on a background thread.  This is always a bad idea, because IIS can and will recycle the Application Pool that your website is running in, and those background threads might be silently aborted.

Comment: I/O bound tasks can also profit. And they are a lot more common. The CPU argument doesn't hold.

Comment: Only if you have multiple independent I/O bound tasks that are bound on different I/O paths, e.g. multiple disks or a disk and a network link.  Parallelizing I/O's that are bound on the same device doesn't buy you anything- in fact, for disks, it usually slows you down.  Anyway, answer edited to indicate that.

Comment: Two disk actions would be doubtful, but any combination of disk/webservice/db is a prime candidate. 2 services or 2 queries might qualify.

Comment: the CPU argument is close to moot unless you expect one request to consume all the resources. by IOs it's usually meant blocking IO that waits for remote response, it's just simple to execute (and process) blocking IO than the non-blocking version.

Answer (score 1):

Threading can be useful in server side programming if you need to return a response and don't want to tie up the server thread, in particular for long running processes that would cause the request to time out.

Comment: IIS typically handles this in most ASP.NET situations.

Answer (score 1):

A thread may be used for actions that last longer than the lifetime of the page request, so yes, it makes sense.

An example would be a thread that spins up a process to encode video. Since this can take some time, the client can be updated later with the encoding progress via AJAX or Comet, or any other number of mechanisms.

Comment: This is almost always a bad idea.  IIS is not background task friendly.  Those tasks should be offloaded to a Windows Service.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the workload and the use case. Request/Response systems are best served by executing them asynchrounously on the client side.

If the workload on the server warrents threading, the work can be done in parallel but each thread should be joined at the end to return a single response.

The bottom line is that if the data you are getting can be loaded faster in parallel, do it, otherwise use async (ajax) calls from the client to prevent the user interface from blocking

Answer (score 1):

Here is a concrete example of how you can still use multiple threads with the ASP.NET programming model. The example assumes that you can break down the tasks required to load a page into independent work items. You then process the work items in parallel and wait for them to complete. I am using the Task Parallel Library to abstract away the explicit creation of threads, but the result is all the same. The ASP.NET programming certainly can accomodate and benefit from a multithreaded design.

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ICollection<WorkItem> workitems = GetWorkItems();

  Parallel.ForEach(workitems,
    (item) =>
    {
      ProcessWorkItem(item);
    });

  // Now that we have all of our work items completed we can continue loading the page.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't go so far as to say threading is useless in ASP.NET, but it's definitely a different model.  For resource requests (page requests) in general, the threading is handled by the system.  That is, Request A from User 1 can take longer than Request B from User 2 and the latter isn't inconvenienced by the former.  Applying that concept to AJAX requests as you suggest and the entire model becomes multi-threaded by default and scales to whatever the hardware can handle.

Spawning a thread *can* be useful if, for some reason, a request *must* spawn some long-running process and needs to respond to the user before the process completes.  Generally non-live processes should be re-factored out of the web application and placed into their own back-end service.  But it's not entirely unheard-of for a page request to spawn a thread that's expected to do something in the background for a few minutes so that the browser isn't waiting the whole time (and likely timing out).